# Replace whitspaces with dashes, make all lowercase

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to combine some code and it's going badly wrong (because I'm rubbish at Javascript). This is my original code:

```
function onSubmit(){
    document.forms["login"]["redirect_to"].value = document.forms["login"]["log"].value;
}
```

I want to strip out the whitespaces and replace with dashes and make everything lowercase, this was my attempt:

```
function onSubmit(){
    var str = document.forms["login"]["log"].value;
    str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    document.forms["login"]["redirect_to"].value = str;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();` replaces the content, but it does not update str. Assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

`.replace` and `toLowerCase` return the new value, they don't transform the original.

Add `str =` to the start of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these two lines:

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    document.forms["login"]["redirect_to"].value = str;
```

Use this:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```